# JSON Stringify 400 Bad Request on AJAX POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, post, csrf

I am receiving 400 Bad Request for the AJAX Post method. I am using Spring Data Rest Services at Backend. Below is the code I am having on front end for JS

```
var url = "/udb/data/SecurityRoleGroup",
        groupData = {id:"",name:"",accesslevel:"",roles:[]};
        groupData.id = groupId.val();
        groupData.name = groupName.val();
        groupData.accesslevel = groupDescription.val();
        groupData.roles = multiselect_to.val();

        $.ajax(url, { type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': _csrfGroup.val(),
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            },
            data: JSON.stringify(groupData),
            contentType: 'application/json',
        })
        .done(function(results) {
            showMessage.html("Group details are saved successfully.");
            showMessage.removeClass().addClass("alert alert-success").show();
        })
        .fail( function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
            showMessage.html("Error : Rolegroup AJAX request failed! Please try again.");
            showMessage.removeClass().addClass("alert alert-danger").show();
        });
```

Although I am serializing the JSON data. Still I am receiving the 400 Bad Request error. Can this error come if some code is breaking on backend or its issue with the request sent to the server?

JAVA Implementation

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "SecurityRoleGroup", path = "SecurityRoleGroup")
public interface SecurityRoleGroupRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<SecurityRoleGroup, Long> {

}
```

Comment: What is the response error message in console ?

Comment: {"cause":null,"message":"Can not handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': type: value deserializer of type org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$UriStringDeserializer does not support them"}

Comment: Your server cannot deserialize your request parameter(s). Basically your request can't be matched to anything the server already knows of.

Comment: I think you need to encode your request in required server format. Or the Request format is not correct. Also check whether the method (POST, GET, PUT) is correct on whatever expected.

Comment: you need not to use the content type header since you have used the type: json

Answer (score 6):

if you have spl characters in your data you need to encode the data before you send to server. Try this

```
$.ajax(url, { type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-Token': _csrfGroup.val(),
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                },
                data: encodeURI(JSON.stringify(groupData)),
                contentType: 'application/json',
            })
```

Comment: I would use encodeURIComponent insted of encodeURI. "encodeURI by itself cannot form proper HTTP GET and POST requests, such as for XMLHTTPRequests, because "&", "+", and "=" are not encoded, which are treated as special characters in GET and POST requests. encodeURIComponent, however, does encode these characters."  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

Comment: why is this working!? we spent 1 week on this problem - thanks.

Comment: (From an Angular POST request to a JAVA server.  This worked).

Answer (score 0):

1.Why you need to send the data converting string you can sent the data as it is
2.you need not to put content type as application/json since you defined as json in data type
3.if you use post method here make sure you are handling the same in the server side